# Simple plugin don't display content

Tags: plugin-development

Trying to learn WP plugin development.

Followed all the instructions.

`plugins/e4-test-1` directory.

Main php file (`e4-test-1.php`):

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Test 1
 * Plugin URI: http://xxxxx.xxx
 * Description: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
 * Version: 1.0.0
 * Author: xxxxxxx
 * Author URI: http://xxxxxx.xxx
 * License: GPL2
 */
```

My one an only php file with code (`testhook.php`):

```
<?php

function testhook() {
     echo 'SOULISSSSSSSSSSSS';
}
add_action( "wp_head", "testhook" );
```

It simply does nothing. View Source doesnot contain the string anywhere.

Of course I have activated the plugin, cleared caches e.t.c

Obviously my noobness stops me from finding the mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call your custom file into your main plugin file. Without doing that, your custom file will not get called. Think of your main plugin file as your themes `functions.php` file and your custom file like a custom file that also holds functions

By default, Wordpress will only read your functions.php, and not your custom functions file. For wordpress to know to load that functions inside the custom file, you need to tell wordpress that there is a custom file with functions it should load. Normally, in a theme, you would use `include` or `require_once`. Here we would do the same, except, your path will differ from themes

So you can try the following in your main plugin file

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/testhook.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to activate the debug mode in config.php:
Set this to true:`define('WP_DEBUG', false);`

Deactivate any plugin you have running to make sure there isn't a Jquery error.

Now run it again. 
Maybe you should also start with something simpeler.
The tag `<script>` wants to run something. Maybe your browser doesn't allow it (for what kind of reason)

Try following:

```
function testhook() {
   echo'TEST';
}
add_action( "wp_head", "testhook" );
```

Comment: I already replaced with echo..Will try debug...where to put it? in the php file of the plugin?

Comment: in your config.php file at the bottom is the following line:`define('WP_DEBUG', false);`. Change the false part to true. Where do you call this function?

Comment: Added, also added debug bar plugin and everything is clear.The code is in proper php file inside the plugin directory

Comment: updated my answer to include file names

Comment: Oke this might be the dumbest solution I can offer you but did you activate your plugin? I just added a new plugin with your code and it works with me. Here is the complete code I used: `<?php

/*
Plugin Name: test
Description: description
Author: name
Version: 1.0
Author URI: http://www.example.com
*/

function testhook() {
     echo 'SOULISSSSSSSSSSSS';
}
add_action( "wp_head", "testhook" );

?>`

Comment: I activate/deactivate many times, although the file with the code says 'inactive'

Comment: What do you mean by 'inactive'? When does this happen?